# Php Excel Library Cell Format

Tags: php, excel, excel-2007

we want to get data in general format only as 92300000000. But sometimes our code creates problem, when cell is in scientific notation format. So how to make code consider cell format as general format even though its in scientific notation or in any other format.

Below is code

```
include("../../excel/PHPExcel.php");
include("../../excel/Excel2007.php");
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
foreach($sheetData as $row){
array_push($array,mysql_real_escape_string(strval($row['A'])));
}
```

Comment: scientific is general format for large numbers... in excel `9000000000000000` + `1` is `9000000000000000` and not `9000000000000001`.... but maybe i'm completely wrong ;P

Comment: how to consider cell as general format though its in scientific notation ?